# Convert a vector to string in matlab and search for this string inside a cell array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, vector

Suppose I have a vector created after concatenating horizontally 3 variables:

```
>>a=1;
>>b=0;
>>c=1;
>>vector=horzcat(a,b,c);
```

Now what i want to do is converting this vector to string and put this vector in a cell table.

```
 >>string=mat2str(vector);
 >>string =

    [1 0 1]

 >> C = cell(2, 2);
 >> C{1}{1}=string

 >> C = 

  {1x1 cell}    []
      []    []
```

My problem is: how to search for this value in a cell array? i tried the following:

```
find(strcmp(C, string))

ans =

Empty matrix: 0-by-1
```

as you can see, matlab can't find this vector converted to string inside the cell array. Is there any easier way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you want this:

```
C{1}{1}=string
```

and not this:

```
C{1,1}=string
```

?

If you use the second method, then `find(strcmp...` will work. The first method won't work because you are making a cell matrix within a cell matrix and then asking strcmp to compare your string directly with a cell...

Comment: I think you can do it simply by `C{1}=string`. the `{1,1}` notation seems not necessary.

Comment: @Adiel sure but it is a 2D matrix so for example it makes more sense to go `C{1,2} = ...` than `C{3} = ...` even though they both work. So to be consistent I went with `C{1,1}` even though sure, `C{1}` does the same thing.